# What size wire do I need for my 50A, 350' well circuit?

Tags: well

I am adding a meter to my home that will be monitoring my well which is approximately 350’ from my home.  I will be running the wire underground and it is only supplying 50 amps.  No other items on system.  What size wire do I need to install?

Comment: We don't need your email. Could you post information about the pump motor? A photo of the nameplate or spec sheet would be ideal.

Comment: We're not a discussion forum, Sharon. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn why posting private contact requests is inappropriate here.

Comment: Yes the HP rating of the motor is needed to determine how much current the wire should be sized for.

Comment: We do need all the relevant details off the name plate.